# How to output an individual element of "$@"?

Tags: bash, parameter

I have read that `$@` is an array that holds the positional parameters.

I have tried to output an element of the `$@` array:

```
echo ${@[1]}
```

But `bash` is giving me this error:

```
test.sh: line 1: ${@[1]}: bad substitution
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`$@` is a ["special parameter"](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Special-Parameters.html#Special-Parameters), not an array; therefore, you cannot access it as an array. You can access the parameters directly, using their position:  `${1}` ... `${n}`.

```sh
$ set -- a b c d e f g h i j k l m n
$ echo "$#"
14
$ echo "${10}"
j
```

---

Because I got curious about the brace behavior for parameters 10+, I ran a test against various shells:

```sh
for shell in ash bash dash fish ksh mksh posh rc sash yash zsh
do
  printf "The %s shell outputs: %s\n" "$shell" "$($shell -c 'set -- a b c d e f g h i j k l m n; echo $10')"
done
```

With these results:

```
The ash shell outputs: j
The bash shell outputs: a0
The dash shell outputs: j
The fish shell outputs:
The ksh shell outputs: a0
The mksh shell outputs: a0
The posh shell outputs: a0
rc: cannot find `set'
The rc shell outputs:
The sash shell outputs: j
The yash shell outputs: a0
The zsh shell outputs: j
```

The curly-brace behavior for shell parameters is explained in the [Shell Command Language](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02) section on Shell Parameter expansion:

> The parameter name or symbol can be enclosed in braces, which are optional except for positional parameters with more than one digit ...

and the `$@` special parameter itself is described on the same page in the [Special Parameters](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_05_02) section.

Comment: Well for 1 to 9 you don't really need the brackets ... I believe this is well known but I think it's better to mention this in the answer.

Comment: You don't need the brackets for 0..9, true, but you do for 10+, and doesn't hurt when using them for 0..9.

Comment: You can do an array slice on `$@`, like `echo "${@:1:1}"` to get the first parameter.  Not sure if there's a case for doing this when you can use `$1`, but it's there.

Comment: `$@` is an array. Only in ksh and bash, arrays are not arrays but more like associative arrays with keys limited to positive integers. In Bourne-like shells where arrays are arrays (yash and zsh), `${@[5]}` works.

Comment: `zsh` outputs a0 when in sh/ksh emulation.

Comment: Most shells output `j` with `${10}`. It is the most portable syntax.

Comment: @isaac the main point of my update was to see how shells handle the un-braced version.

Answer (score 5):

The `$@` is in fact a list of values, not an array. Array syntax doesn't really work. They [are called "Positional Parameters"](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Positional-Parameters.html) and usually accessed by the `$4` syntax (for example).

In bash:

```
$ set -- a b c d e f g h i j k l m n
$ echo $6
f
$ echo "${11}"
k
$ echo "${@:11:1}"
k
```

With an index:

```
$ i=11
$ echo "${@:i:1}"
k
$ echo "${!i}"
k
```

On older shells there is no solution but to use eval (beware of risks):

```
$ eval 'var=$'"{$i}"
$ echo "$var"
k
```

#### Loops

Loops are easy to manage, just use `for var; do …; done`

```
$ for pos; do printf '%s:' "$pos"; done; echo
a:b:c:d:e:f:g:h:i:j:k:l:m:n:
```

The shell automatically makes each value in the list available for each loop.

Comment: I guess one way to describe it is that it's not an array but rather the result of applying `${...[@]}` _to_ a special nameless array variable.